# Can't add more than four keyboard layouts

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, layout

I can't add more than 4 keyboard layouts on my ubuntu. It just won't let me add more. And I in need of at least 4 more. Anyone else encountered this problem and can give me some advice?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd need to know which version of Ubuntu you are using to come up with a working workaround (you can just hover over the tags and click on `edit tags` and add e.g. 10.04 or 11.10).

Answer (score 4):

This is [a known bug/limitation](https://askubuntu.com/a/21844/3037). The only workaround is to set up a shortcut to a script that switches between sets of keyboard layouts.

Based on [this post on UF.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10984263&postcount=14):

1. Setup the first four layouts, then run the following two commands in a terminal:

   ```
   gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/layouts
   gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts
   ```
2. Setup the second four layouts, then again run the above commands.
3. Now open the text editor gedit (press <kbd>Super</kbd>, type *gedit*, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and paste the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   layout_one="[de deadgraveacute,al,ara,be]"
   layout_one_dconf="['de\tdeadgraveacute', 'al', 'ara', 'be']"

   layout_two="[de deadgraveacute,ba,ph,gb]"
   layout_two_dconf="['de\tdeadgraveacute', 'ba', 'ph', 'gb']"

   current=$(gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/layouts)

   if [ "$current" == "$layout_one" ]
   then
       new="$layout_two"
       new_dconf="$layout_two_dconf"
   else
       new="$layout_one"
       new_dconf="$layout_one_dconf"
   fi

   gconftool-2 --set --type list --list-type string /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/layouts "$new"
   gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "$new_dconf"
   ```

   Make sure to replace the layouts for `layout_one`, `layout_one_dconf`, `layout_two`, and `layout_two_dconf` in that script with the output from steps 1 and 2. If there's empty space in a layout name, make sure to use a tab character rather than spaces (just copy and paste from the terminal).
4. Save it somewhere, e.g. */home/YOURUSERNAME/Documents/scripts/keyboard-layout-switch*
5. From a terminal, run:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/Documents/scripts/keyboard-layout-switch
   ```

   to make the script executable.
6. Now you need to set a shortcut to call that script: press <kbd>Super</kbd>, type *keyboard*, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. In the keyboard settings, go to the *Shortcuts* tab and on the left click on *Custom Shortcuts*.
8. Click on the tiny `+` icon to create a new shortcut with:

   - Name: *Change Keyboard Layouts*
   - Command: `/home/YOURUSERNAME/Documents/scripts/keyboard-layout-switch`

   [image]
9. Click on apply, then click on `Disabled` to set the desired shortcut:

   [image]
10. You now should be able to switch between two sets of four keyboard layouts with the shortcut you set.

Comment: Seems solved now! Yay!