# Using keyboard layout I don't physically have

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, onboard

I want to have a virtual keyboard with Japanese and Arabic, which my physical keyboard doesn't have stickers for (and doesn't have enough space even if I bought).

I thought of using it through `onboard`, but it works only for the current layout.

Is there a way to either configure a layout to `onboard` other than the one currently used, or configure layouts with setxkbmap that aren't regularly toggeled through (So I can toggle only English and Russian usually, but sometimes go to the other languages)?

Comment: You can easily [install and] switch between keyboard layouts, and use `onboard` to see the current keyboard layout. I use this method to switch between different European languages. I have not used it for Japanese and Arabic, but I think it could work. Let us hope that someone who knows one of these languages will see your question and and give a good answer :-)

Comment: I just don't want the languages I rarely type in to interfere with my daily usage... It'll be inconvenient to toggle through 4 languages when I just need 2

Comment: I am running Lubuntu, and I get Arabic characters on my `onboard` via `setxkbmap ar`. But not much happens with `setxkbmap jp`. In the latter case I guess you need to install something, for example a language pack for Japanese. But I am sure there are many people who have better answers than my comments.

Comment: Adding or removing an input language takes a few seconds. Why not simply add Arabic or Mozc via the GUI when you need it, and then remove it?

Comment: @sudodus: Japanese is usually typed using a special input method instead of a particular keyboard layout.

Comment: there are existing scripts built with `setxkbmap` or `gsettings` to provide more than 4 layouts.  you could configure a solution that uses that sort of script to provide your standard configuration (`us,ru`) but when activated switch to another layout set (`us,ru,jp,ar`?  `us,jp,ar`?).  see https://askubuntu.com/q/107945/669043 and similar questions.