# Problem with multiple keyboard layouts

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I've just switched to Lubuntu 18.04 from Windows and I'm still trying to get the hang of the system, and the limit of 4 keyboard layouts came as a highly unpleasant surprise, since I usually use at least 6. The Keyboard Layout Handler had no problem with me adding 6 layouts, but it only switches between the top 4. So far, I've put the 4 I use most frequently there and I'll alter the rest manually as needed, but it's still rather annoying.

I saw the answer posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107945/cant-add-more-than-four-keyboard-layouts), but already in the second line my terminal says "No such schema “org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard”", and I have no idea what to do next. Generally, I have next to no experience with the terminal and with where things are in Lubuntu, so concrete instructions would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change keyboard layout in Lubuntu 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788244/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-lubuntu-15-10)

Comment: Please see the answer to the duplicate question. I think that the 4 layout limitation is history since long.

Comment: Alas, no. I've edited above - I can *put* more than 4 layouts in the KLH, but either clicking on the flag or using the keyboard shortcut cycles only between the first 4, ignoring all the others.